# Keep getting "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'source'" error

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord.py, youtube-dl

Everytime I try to run play command in my bot, I get this error in the terminal, kind of new to coding so not exactly sure whats going on. It was working just fine, then it started not to work.

```
import discord

from discord.ext import commands

from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

class music_cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False

        self.music_queue = []
        self.YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
        self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}

        self.vc = None

    def search_yt(self, item):
        with YoutubeDL(self.YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
            try:
                info = ydl.extract_info("ytsearch:%s" % item, download=False)['entries'][0]
            except Exception:
                return False
        return {'sourcffmpege': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}
    
    def play_next(self):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url = self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg", source=m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())
        else:
            self.is_playing = False

    async def play_music(self, ctx):
        if len(self.music_queue) > 0:
            self.is_playing = True

            m_url=self.music_queue[0][0]['source']

            if self.vc == None or not self.vc.is_connected():
                self.vc = await self.music_queue[0][1].connect()

                if self.vc == None:
                    await ctx.send("Could not connect to the voice channel")
                    return
            else:
                await self.vc.move_to(self.music_queue[0][1])

            self.music_queue.pop(0)

            self.vc.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="ffmpeg", source=m_url, **self.FFMPEG_OPTIONS), after=lambda e: self.play_next())

    @commands.command(name="play", aliases=["p", "playing"], help="Play the selected song from youtube")
    async def play(self, ctx, *args):
        query = " ".join(args)

        voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
        if voice_channel is None:
            await ctx.send("Connect to a voice channel!")
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()
        else:
            song = self.search_yt(query)
            if type(song) == type(True):
                await ctx.send("Could not download the song. Incorrect format, try a different keyword")
            else:
                await ctx.send("Song added to the queue")
                self.music_queue.append([song, voice_channel])

                if self.is_playing == False:
                    await self.play_music(ctx)

    @commands.command(name="pause", help="Pauses the current song being played")
    async def pause(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_playing:
            self.is_playing = False
            self.is_paused = True
            self.vc.pause()
        elif self.is_paused:
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="resume", aliases=["r"], help="Resumes playing the current song")
    async def resume(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.is_paused:
            self.is_playing = True
            self.is_paused = False
            self.vc.resume()

    @commands.command(name="skip", aliases=["s"], help="Skips the currently played song")
    async def skip(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.vc:
            self.vc.stop()
            await self.play_music(ctx)

    @commands.command(name="queue", aliases=["q"], help="Displays all the songs currently in the queue")
    async def queue(self, ctx):
        retval = ""

        for i in range(0, len(self.music_queue)):
            if i > 5: break
            retval += self.music_queue[i][0]['title'] + '\n'

        if retval != "":
            await ctx.send(retval)
        else:
            await ctx.send("No music in queue.")
    
    @commands.command(name="clear", aliases=["c", "bin"], help="Stops the current song and clears the queue")
    async def clear(self, ctx, *args):
        if self.vc != None and self.is_playing:
            self.vc.stop()
        self.music_queue = []
        await ctx.send("Music queue cleared")

    @commands.command(name="leave", aliases=["l"], help="Kicks the bot from the voice channel")
    async def leave(self, ctx):
        self.is_playing = False
        self.is_paused = False
        await self.vc.disconnect()

async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(music_cog(bot))
```

this is my music_cogs.py, this is where error is coming from

was working just fine then it started to give me this error after a while.

```
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\poopt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 229, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\poopt\Code\cool_bot\cogs\music_cog.py", line 77, in play
    await self.play_music(ctx)
  File "c:\Users\poopt\Code\cool_bot\cogs\music_cog.py", line 44, in play_music
    m_url=self.music_queue[0][0]['source']
KeyError: 'source'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 1349, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\poopt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 1023, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\poopt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 238, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: KeyError: 'source'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.  That said, you have ```return {'sourcffmpege': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}```   shouldn't that just be ```return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}```?

Comment: added sorry : | -- THANK YOU THAT WORKED!

Answer (score 1):

[From the Python docs:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError)

> exception **KeyError**:
>
> Raised when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of existing keys.

This means that you are trying to access an entry in a dictionary with a key that doesn't exist.

Your error lies in your `search_yt()` function where you return a dictionary with the key `sourcffmpege` instead of `source`. This should fix your problem:

```
return {'source': info['formats'][0]['url'], 'title': info['title']}
```